# Multiple Event Names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query thats supposed to pull consultations that do not have a follow up event.

```
SELECT p.person_nbr
, p.last_name + ',' + p.first_name as [Full Name]
, pm.last_name as Provider
, pe.enc_id 
, e.event
, pe.enc_timestamp 
FROM person p 

JOIN patient_encounter pe
 ON p.person_id = pe.person_id
JOIN appointments a 
on a.enc_id = pe.enc_id
JOIN events e 
ON a.event_id = e.event_id
JOIN provider_mstr pm 
    ON pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
 --where  pe.enc_timestamp >= '20180713' and pe.enc_timestamp <= '20181030'

GROUP BY p.person_nbr,  p.last_name + ',' + p.first_name , pm.last_name , 
pe.enc_id 
, e.event , pe.enc_timestamp 

HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN e.event like 'Consult' and pe.enc_timestamp >= 
'20180713' AND pe.enc_timestamp <= '20181030' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND 

  SUM(CASE WHEN e.event like 'Follow Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1


order by p.person_nbr
    ;
```

I thought if a person had a consultation within the specified dates in the having clause and then the separate statement saying they didnt have a follow up it would work but I get no results.  Ive tried moving the dates in the where clause as well. I believe Im not getting results because its thinking im asking if a single event is both a consult and follow up but i want it to return  single consultations that dont have a follow up ever in the future

Comment: If i change the second having statement to <= 1 I still get consultations that have future follow ups

Comment: please add table structure and example data

Comment: ...and desired results

Comment: desired results.. list of person numbers who have a record with event type 'Consult' and no records of event type 'Follow up'